# LUIS Import app from json file throws BadArgument version id cannot be null error

Tags: artificial-intelligence, botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I downloaded the bot application samples from github, and opened the luis application through visualstudio and tried to import the json file to creat a new app in luis.ai portal, but it was throwing error

**"BadArgument: Version ID cannot be null or empty."**

Answer (score 6):

Open the .JSON file in notepad, and add the version parameter as highlighted in the below sample. i.e. `VersionId: "0.1"`

```
{
    "luis_schema_version": "1.3.0",

    "versionId": "0.1",

    "name": "LuisBot",
    "desc": "",
    "culture": "en-us",
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When we import new app on LUIS portal, it will make a request to this URL:

> https://[location].api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/api/v2.0/apps/import[?appName]

In [LUIS Programmatic APIs v2.0 documentation](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c31), we can find that the response 400 error will be returned if import JSON is incorrect. And the error message will reference the exact property that is causing the problem, as you see: Version ID cannot be null or empty.

Next time, before you import an new app, you can compare your json file with the sample LUIS application structure that provided in that documentation. And the documentation shows the causes of some issues, which can help us quickly troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 0):

even if you provided the versionID, the app "name" is also mandatory so you have to fill it out.

Actually the import wizard asks you to provide the name. just leave it empty and make sure that you have updated the name in your .json file